# Mapping simple function to print date and time stamp on Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, datetime

I am new to the Google Earth Engine Python API, and I am trying to create functions that when mapped over a collection will print some metadata (e.g. time stamp, band names) but I always get the same error:

> EEException: ValueNode is empty

Here is the code:

```
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

# Getting the Sentinel 1 image over the study site
collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD').filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(121.1737372,24)).filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-01-30')
collectionList = collection.toList(collection.size())
sentinel1 = ee.Image(collectionList.get(1)).select('VH')

##Function to print the dates of a collection
def printDate(image):
  date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'))
  print('Time stamp:'+str(date.format('Y-M-d').getInfo()))

collection.map(printDate)

def collectionBands(img):
  bands = img.bandNames()
  print('band names:'+str(bands.getInfo()))

collection.map(collectionBands)
```

Answer (score 8):

From the JavaScript docs (it's essentially identical to the Python docs, but easier to get to, as it's there in the code editor):

> **ImageCollection.map(algorithm, dropNulls)**
>
> [...]
>
> algorithm (Function): The operation to map over the images or features
>   of the collection. A JavaScript function that receives an image or
>   features and returns one. The function is called only once and the
>   result is captured as a description, so it cannot perform imperative
>   operations or rely on external state.
>
> [...]

This is a bit cryptical, but it implies that it doesn't make sense to print inside the function you pass to `.map()`. The function is called only once, no matter how many images you have in the collection. In addition to this, you'll get an error if you call `.getInfo()` inside that function, and the function **must** return an `ee.Feature` or `ee.Image`.

Here's how you could get the dates and band names printed:

```
collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD') \
    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(121.1737372,24)) \
    .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-01-30')

dates = ee.List(collection \
    .aggregate_array('system:time_start')) \
    .map(lambda time_start: 
         ee.Date(time_start).format('Y-MM-dd')
    ) \
    .getInfo()

band_names = collection \
    .map(lambda image: 
         image.set('bandNames', image.bandNames())
   ) \
    .aggregate_array('bandNames') \
    .getInfo()

for date in dates:
    print(date)

for band_name in band_names:
    print(band_name)
```